# How to have only inner margins in wrapped float left list

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I was wondering how I could have a wrapped list of `<li>` elements using float: left; that didn't have any outer margins, only margins in between the elements. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tysonzero/my2rtgbt/) is an example of what I DON'T want as it has margins around the outside of the list whereas I want the border of the outer list to be touching the borders of the inner list items. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tysonzero/4vvojx75/) is an example of what I DO want however I find this solution to be hacky, as it requires the use of a second container outside the `<ul>` to act as the list border, if you stick a border on the `<ul>` itself you will see that it is still 10px away from the list items, I also prefer avoiding negative margins unless I really need to use them.

It seems as though float is designed to pull elements like pictures to the side and allow text to flow either side of them, and not as a way to make horizontal wrapping list, due to the natural behavior of not considering floated child elements when determining height. Because of this I was also wondering if it would be better to use something like flexbox for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this is a fundamental abuse of float.  Flexbox would be one way to approach this, yes.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Do you have any ideas other than flexbox? While I do REALLY like the premise of flexbox the lack of opera mini support even on the most updated version of opera is annoying. I don't care that much about older versions of browsers, anything 2 or more versions behind I have zero intention of supporting or even implementing shivs for, but I want to support the current version of preferably every browser as well as the last version for those who do not update immediately.

Comment: Container with negative margins, table with cellpadding and negative margins, or display relative nonsense, I suppose.

Comment: In that case I will probably go for flexbox. I will look into it a little more first.